# IDEA: How to autoformat JSP

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

Using `IntelliJ Idea`, is there a way to autoformat `JSP`, similar to how `Java` files are formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Code` | **Reformat Code** works for JSP pages in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition when your JSP file extension is mapped to the *Java Server Page files* in `Settings` | `File Types`.